# Display image from filename in a database record to a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I want to display the picture found in the file location that is in the field "Picture" I have this code that shows the fields in the datagridview but I cannot figure how to properly code image from file.

Update - this below code works fine

enter code here

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class test
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Private Sub test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    getthedata() ' this does a query and adds a column to the query data datatable
    Filldatagrid() ' This fills the datagridview named DG1
End Sub
Sub getthedata()
    sel = "select * from dog"
    DataConnection()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sel, con)
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim imageColumn As New DataColumn
    imageColumn.ColumnName = "Picture"
    imageColumn.DataType = GetType(System.Drawing.Image)
    dt.Columns.Add(imageColumn)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row("Picture") = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(row("pic"))
    Next
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    con.Close()
End Sub
Sub Filldatagrid()
    dg1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dg1.RowTemplate.Height = 150 ' this is the larger size to accomodate the image
    dg1.ColumnCount = 4
    dg1.DataSource = dt
    dg1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "ID"
    dg1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    dg1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Name"
    dg1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 15)
    dg1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
    dg1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Nam"
    dg1.Columns(1).Width = 100
    dg1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Birthday"
    dg1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 15)
    dg1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "Birth"
    dg1.Columns(2).Width = 150
    dg1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "Pic"
    dg1.Columns(3).Visible = False
    Dim dgvImageColumn As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    dgvImageColumn.DataPropertyName = "Picture"
    dgvImageColumn.Width = 150
    dgvImageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
    dg1.Columns.Add(dgvImageColumn)
End Sub
```

End Class

The database records are:
Id  Nam Birth   Pic Comments
1   Brody   5/15/2015   C:\Users\JRS89\Dropbox\Photos\dogs\Brody\Brody.jpg
2   Bella   5/1/2015    C:\Users\JRS89\Dropbox\Photos\dogs\Bella\Bella.jpg
3   Benji   5/15/2016   C:\Users\JRS89\Dropbox\Photos\dogs\Benji\Benji.jpg

Comment: There are quite a few different steps to this you've not really indicated exactly what you problem is.  Guessing you've got one column in your table that is the file name.  So you probably want to add an unbound DataGridViewImageColumn to display your image, then implementing a image object to load the file for display.  Maybe edit your question with a little more detail on exactly what you're struggling with

Comment: Basically I want to display my records in a datagridview but I want the field that contains the file location to be displayed as the image rather than the file location.

Comment: The database records are:        
Id | Nam Birth Pic Comments    
1 Brody 5/15/2015 C:\Users\JRS89\Dropbox\Photos\dogs\Brody\Brody.jpg     
2 Bella 5/1/2015 C:\Users\JRS89\Dropbox\Photos\dogs\Bella\Bella.jpg     
3 Benji 5/15/2016 C:\Users\JRS89\Dropbox\Photos\dogs\Benji\Benji.jpg

Comment: You may find the [Image.FromFile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) useful. There is a `DataGridViewImageColumn` that you can add to your grid. Then loop through the rows of the grid and add the image to each `DataGridViewImageCell` on that row by using method above and the path in the other cell. You can also use a `DataTable` with an `Image` type column.

Comment: I added code to populate the Img cell with the image but it just shows [x]

Comment: I found an answer that does the trick "Display image in Datagridview"

Comment: enter code here